# Concept Confused : Cloud Interaction with Wordpress in GCP and APP with Spring

Tags: mysql, spring, wordpress, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

I'm quite new to wordpress and GCP, learning programming less than one year.

Now I'm writing a project using wordpress in GCP and mobile app in the frontend and MySQL in GCP and Spring Boot as server and controller.

In GCP, Wordpress, MySQL, Apache, etc are included and managed.

[image: my concept architecture]

As you can see in the architecture I assume they will work, there is no need to send Rest API to spring boot and react to DB. I would like to know if I am right about the basic concept.

There is shared information in wordpress and app, for example, membership data.
In app, we send request to spring and spring reacts with DB in GCP, as wordpress acquires data from DB again, a new member info is loaded automatically in the frontend.
And in wordpress, request is sent to DB in GCP and Data is renewed. Once the app acquires data thru spring and DB, the new in is loaded.

I have the issue because the mentor said it is not usual practice for web to react directly with DB, and the co-workers insist establishing a connection between web and spring. Why?

The initial concept is to create a web and app that shares same database, but create different functionality, web for selling, app for interactive activities. We learned the basics in java, spring and web, but we are really unfamiliar with network concept.
(The frontend part and DB establishment are finished. We are working on the Server part.)

If there is any clarification or any suggestion to modify the whole procedure, it's well appreciated.
If there is any nothing I did not explain so well, I will try harder.

Comment: Your question is very confusing and is not clear what problem you are solving. Is your goal to share a WordPress database with a Spring Boot application? Where is the Spring Boot application running? Rewrite your question into a software/programming problem with code, errors, etc. If you are not at that point, go back to your advisor for more advice.

Comment: Yes, we are trying to share a Wordpress database with a spring boot application, and that is just for the communication with APP.

Comment: I'm only asking if it is necessary to break the connection between Wordpress and database ,and then create a new connection with it thru spring boot.

Comment: What do you mean "break the connection"? Databases support multiple connections from multiple clients at the same time. WordPress and Spring Boot can both access the database at the same time. I am ignoring features like locking - WordPress does not lock the database.